# perl - trouble understanding array of arrays

Tags: arrays, perl, multidimensional-array

I am trying to make an array of arrays and then reference them.

I make somethign like:

```
sub foobar
{
 my @array;
 my $i;
 for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i=$i+1)
 {
  my @row;
  $row[0] = $i;
  $row[1] = foo($bar);
  push @array , [@row];
 }
 return \@array;
}
```

I can get to the values via:

```
$array->[x]->[y];
```

However I don't understand why the second -> is needed. $array->[x] I understand because $array is a reference. But isn't $array->[x] meant to be an array? Why doesn't this work:

```
my @notarray = $array->[x];
```

What exactally is not array filled with now? Because it certainly doesn't seem to be an array containing $i , foo($bar)

How would $array->[x]->[y] be different for a reference to an array of references to arrays?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second `->` isn't needed, actually.

Here's the deal: All Perl array values and hash values must be scalars. That means either a string, number, or array/hash reference (and not a plain old array or hash).

So the first `->` operator dereferences the array and gets at the x'th row. In there is-- not an array, but an array reference. So in order to get to the data in there, you'd theoretically need another `->` operator.

But get this. Perl is smart: It knows that after one array or hash access, if another access happens, the only way this is possible is through an array/hash reference (because your first array/hash access MUST return a scalar)! So you don't need the second arrow after all.

See [perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html) for more details.

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I had come to believe that it was possible to have arrays of arrays, but they are really arrays of references.

Answer (score 2):

When you

```
push @array, [@row];
```

you are pushing a *reference* to an array. This is necessary because of Perl's rule that arrays are flattened. So $array->[x] is a reference to the row array, not the row array itself. However, between subscripts, the arrow is optional. So `$array->[x]->[y]` is exactly the same as `$array->[x][y]` (which is exactly the same as `${$array}[x][y]`, etc.)

This is all explained in the [Perl reference tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html)

Comment: If I am pushing a reference then why is each row still different? Shouldn't they be refering to the same thing?

Comment: @kiasectomondo: You're creating a fresh anonymous reference every time. If you just pushed `\@array` each time (for the same `@array`) that would refer to the same thing.

Comment: @kiasectormondo => The rows would only refer to the same thing if you had declared the `@row` array outside of the loop, and taken a reference to it via `\@row`.  The `[@row]` syntax creates a shallow copy of the array, and returns the new reference.  In your case, since you are declaring `my @row` inside the loop, you can just use `\@row` and it will work fine.